# React Typescript how to pass props with types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to get better with Typescript in React

I have a super simple app where I have `App.tsx` with a useState for an array of objects

```
import List from './components/List';

interface IState{
  name: string
  age: number
}

function App() {

  const [people, setpeople] = useState<IState[]>([
    {
      name: 'Chris',
      age: 20
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      age: 28
    },
    {
      name: 'Paul',
      age: 23
    }
  ])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <List people={people}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to pass this as a prop into another component `List.tsx`.

```
interface IProps{
    name: string
    age: number
  }

const List = (people:IProps[]) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {people.map(person => (
                <h2>{person.name}</h2>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default List;
```

I have types for the object in `App.tsx` and I'm trying to use the same types in `List.tsx`

The problem in `App.tsx` at `<List people={people}/>` on people I get

```
Type '{ people: IState[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps[]'.
  Property 'people' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps[]'
```

How do I pass the data in the prop with types ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `props` is the top level object that contains all props passed into the component, so you should either destructure it, or change the interface:

**Quick fix: destructure props**

```
const List = ({ people }: { people: IProps[] }) => { ... }
```

**Better fix: Change the typing of `IProps` so It defines the nested `people` key**

```
interface IProps{
    people: Array<{
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }>
}

const List = ({ people }: IProps) => { ... }
```

---

### Suggestion

Some additional tip: instead of declaring the same prop interface across two files, which means you need to update them in multiple locations should you change your mind later, you can always make `List` export the `people` prop (or actually, the atomised version, say `IPerson`) and then let the consuming parent import it instead. An example:

```
// List.tsx
export interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
interface IProps {
    people: IPerson[];
}
const List = ({ people }: IProps) => { ... }
```

Then...

```
// App.tsx
import List, { IPerson } from './components/List';
const [people, setpeople] = useState<IPerson[]>([ ... ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export your interface in the first file, and then import it in the second file

```
export interface IState{
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

And the to use the same interface in List.tsx.,

```
import { IState} from './List';
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix your issue is to export the `IState` from `App.tsx` and import in `List`, and use it like so:

```
import { IState } from "../App"; // use the corect path

interface IProps {
  people: IState;
}

const List = ({ people }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {people.map((person) => (
        <h2>{person.name}</h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Here is how you would export the interface in `App.tsx`:

```
export interface IState{
  name: string
  age: number
}
```